# Objective-c KVO: object vs changeDictionary

Tags: ios, properties, key-value-observing

I'm using KVO in an iOS app to notify a viewController when a property on an object changes. When I addObserver I specify `options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew`.

In `observeValueForKeyPath` I can get the value of the property in two ways: from the object that's passed to `observeValueForKeyPath`. Or from the `NSDictionary` that's passed to the same method.

**Will these two approaches to getting the value of the updated property always return the same result?**

Recall I'm specifying `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` as the options when I addObserver. From [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) it's sounds like specifying `NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial` could result in a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the common case, yes, these objects should be the same, although it would be possible to contrive a scenario where they weren't (i.e. a custom getter that generates a new value on every call, or something like that.)  `NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial` won't have any bearing on the contents of that dictionary, it just determines whether or not the observer is notified immediately vs. waiting for the first value change after adding the observer. This is useful if you need some state in the observer to be "primed."